# Unable to make use of JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_CELLULAR in JobService

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, jobservice

In our app, we want to bifurcate Wifi and Cellular related calls. We have set the target to 28.

The code looks like below for scheduling cellular based. But, we are unable to set `NETWORK_TYPE_CELLULAR`.

```
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, CellularJobServiceTest.class);

    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(125,componentName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_CELLULAR)
            .setPeriodic(10000).build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

    if(resultCode==JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS){
        Log.e(TAG,"Cellular : Job scheduled successfully");
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG,"Cellular : Job schedule failed.");
    }
```

The Android documentation says `NETWORK_TYPE_METERED` is deprecated and to make use of `NETWORK_TYPE_CELLULAR` instead.

Reference from Android documentation:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 28. Cellular networks may be
>   unmetered, or Wi-Fi networks may be metered, so this isn't a good way
>   of selecting a specific transport. Instead, use `NETWORK_TYPE_CELLULAR`
>   or NetworkRequest.Builder.addTransportType(int) if your job requires a
>   specific network transport.

But Android studio throws **`Wrong constant`** error.

It would be really awesome if I get to know why I am unable to set it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have not installed or updated `Android API 28` platform. Please check it.

Comment: @VicJordan I have installed Android API 28 revision 6 and SDK tools 28.0.2. I am unable to see further updates in SDK Manager.